Location of roots of polynomials: Understanding the proof
Assume a polynomial:
$$p(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1z^1+a_0$$
I am going throught the proof of the theorem that locates the roots of a polynomial inside an open ball. The theorem is as follows:

All the roots of the polynomial lie in $B(0,\rho)=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|< \rho\}$ with $$\rho = 1+ |a_n|^{-1}\max_{0\leq k <n}|a_k|$$

Particularly, there is a part of the proof that says the following:

Assume $\max_{0\leq k <n}|a_k|>0$ hence $\rho > 1$. If $|z|\geq \rho$ then we have
$$|p(z)|\geq |a_nz^n|-|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0|$$

I cannot see the reason why this inequality holds. It might have to do with the definition of $\rho$ but cannot figure out. Any suggestions?

Isn't $|x+y|\ge |x|-|y|$?

@MathArt is right—this is just the triangle inequality in slightly disguised form: Start with $|z-y| \le |z|+|{-}y| = |z|+|y|$, and then set $z=x+y$ and rearrange.

Thanks! This is the correct answer, the rest of the proof followed nicely. If you post it as answer I will accept it.
